# Apache2: ReWrite rule not showing up in address bar?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2, rewrite

I have a domain, example.com.

Here is my apache2 ReWrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?uname=$1 [L]
```

When I go to http://example.com/Eamorr, http://example.com/Eamorr appears in the address bar of my browser.

I want http://www.example.com/index.php?uname=Eamorr to appear in the address bar! (my javascript needs to parse the GET arguments)

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a redirect to that `RewriteRule`.  Change `[L]` to `[R,L]`.

That'll start a redirect loop, though.  You'll likely want to change it to not match `index.php`.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the response. Sorry about the late reply - I fell asleep! How would I change it to not match index.php?

Comment: Hey, when I changed it to [R,L] and go to http://example.com/Eamorr, I get http://example.com/home/eamorr/sites/example.com/www/index.php?uname=Eamorr in the address bar. It's as if it goes to the document root!

Comment: @Eamorr Hmm, relative path funkiness.  Change your redirect to have the full URL; `http://www.example.com/index.php?uname=$1`.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! You are my hero for the day!